# How to capture video out of stream in c/c++ in windows?

Tags: c++, windows, streaming

What's the most recommended way to go?

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty big topic. Try looking at OpenCV. It is nice for image and video manipulation, and you can stream video from files and webcams.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [DirectX](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/directx/default.aspx) "Filter Graphs". You can use a simple tool from the DirectX SDK called 'Graph Edit' to construct a sequence of DirectShow Filters which can do things like capture video streams from a TV card or decode an MPEG/AVI file and then operate on the data stream and ultimately render it to video/audio or a file.

Most of the [DirectShow samples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd375468(VS.85).aspx) are in VC++.

Comment: There is no filter in directshow that can deal with streams directly.

Comment: Please give more information about the stream and then the community can better help you.

Comment: No specific stream, I just need an example to deal with stream in order to get started.